# Modify get tags using htaccess/mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL, for example:

http://server1.website.com/process.aspx?agentid=189&txtDepCity1=DUS&txtArrCity1=MIA&TripType=rdbOneWay&txtDate1=01/20/2014&ddlPaxADT=2&ddlPaxCHD=3&ddlPaxINF=1

I would like to convert to:

http://server2.website.com/search/7HW-1/DUS-MIA/01-20-2014/2-3-1-Y

I've told my server to handle aspx as PHP using:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .aspx
```

What syntax would I have to place in htaccess to insert a GET parameter into a URL rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

May be this [tested on Debian/Apache2]:
  In /.htaccess,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} server1\.website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule process\.aspx http://server2.website.com/search/7HW-1/DUS-MIA/01-20-2014/2-3-1-Y [L,QSA,R]
```